# How do I proof that this is a metric in R?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

I've been struggling to proof that:
$\displaystyle |\frac{x}{1+|x|}-\frac{y}{1+|y|}|=0 \Leftrightarrow x=y$. This way $\Leftarrow$ has been easy but i don't know how to proof the other way. I tried a distinction of cases but it didn't really work out the way I wanted. Has anyone got a tip for me?

Comment: You could try showing the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+\vert x\vert}$ is increasing (and hence injective).

Comment: Checking cases should work. There are 4 possible cases ($x \geq 0, \leq 0$ and $y \geq 0, \leq 0$). But note that two of these cases lead to contradictions, because if $x$ and $y$ have different sign, then the two fractions cannot be equal (denominator is always positive).

Comment: That was also one of my ideas but i can't use differential calculus since we didn't tacle that topic yet in analysis. Do you have an idea how i can show that this function is increasing without using differential calculus?

Comment: Are $x,y$ supposed to be real-valued?

Comment: @DerekH. I suspect so because the title says in $R$. Really should say $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @DanRust I used this and it worked really well, I wonder why I didn't come up with this simple solution myself. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One observation is that if $|\frac{x}{1+|x|}-\frac{y}{1+|y|}|=0$ then $x,y$ has to be both positive or both negative. Thus we can consider two different cases.

Case 1: Both positive. Thus we have $|\frac{x}{1+x}-\frac{y}{1+y}|=0$. In other words, $\frac{x}{1+x}=\frac{y}{1+y}$. Now use derivatives if necesary, because $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}$ is one to one, we have $x=y$. Alternatively, suggested by Dan, one could just multiply through to have $$x+xy=y+yx$$ and thus $x=y$. (We are allowed to multiply through since neither $x$ nor $y$ were assumed to be negative.

Case 2: Both negative. This is similar to Case 1.

Comment: You don't need derivatives. Just multiply through by the denominators.

Comment: @DanRust Good point Dan!

Answer (score 1):

If $z=\frac{x}{1+|x|}$ then $1-|z|=\frac{1}{1+|x|}$, so $x=\frac{z}{1-|z|}$.

Comment: [+1] Your solution is interesting, but you should hopefully have said that the questions boils down to the **injectivity** of function $f:\mathbb R \to (-1,1)$ defined by $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{1+|x|}$, a property that will be a consequence of the fact  that $f$ possesses an inverse that you establish.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $|z|=0$ if and only if $z=0$ for $z\in\mathbb{R}$, i.e., $x-y+x|y|-|x|y=0$. It suffices to show the quantity $|x|y-x|y|=0$ for all $x,y$ such that the equation holds. This is easy, however; if $x,y$ share the same sign the result is clear. Otherwise, as @JustWandering mentioned, the equation does not hold since the two terms
\begin{equation}
\frac{x}{1+|x|},\enspace-\frac{y}{1+|y|}
\end{equation}
cannot 'cancel' when added.